# Why does meta SO have a mortarboard badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

The mortarboard badge is obtained when you earn the daily rep maximum for the first time. However, meta doesn't have rep, so it seems impossible to even get it on meta. I don't think 20 upvotes awards it either (which would equate to 200 rep) because my last post had 53 upvotes, and the badge wasn't awarded.

I also don't believe you get it on meta when you get it on regular SO, because badges don't appear to be shared between the two (commentator badge, for example).

So why does meta SO have the Mortarboard, Epic, and Legendary badges?

Comment: @AndrewMedico I saw that question prior to asking this one, I do not believe them do be duplicates

Comment: It is possible to get the badge. 387 people have Mortarboard on Meta as of today: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard

Answer (score 1):

I've got the Mortarboard badge on meta. You have to get the theoretical rep (such as 20 answer upvotes in one UTC day) to get it.

Epic and Legendary are presumably the same for their respective conditions.